# Como hacer lista de seleccion para usuarios de mi pagina web

Tags: javascript, html, sql, html5

Soy algo nuevo en el mundo de la programación y tengo la siguiente duda en el siguiente contexto:

Estoy elaborando una pagina web donde uno podra ingresar con su cuenta de usuario y hacer publicaciones, comentar publicaciones de otros usuarios, etc. La duda que me surge es:

¿Como puedo hacer una barra de selección para que mis usuarios puedan seleccionar a que pais/ region pertenecen o bien, en que pais/ region buscan por ejemplo: una casa, empleo, lo que sea para agregar al formulario de registro de mi pagina web y como declararla en la base de datos de usuarios (creo que tendría que hacerla de nuevo) y en la pagina?

Gracias de antemano

[image: Algo como lo de la imagen]

Comment: Deberías modificar tu pregunta. Tu pregunta es muy abierta y podría contestarse con "usa un select", hace falta saber qué tienes pensado utilizar: algún framework de javascript para el front, qué utilizarás para el back: php, java, .net, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la etiqueta select:

```html
<select id="opciones">
    <option value="valor1"> Opcion 1</option>
    <option value ="valor2"> Opcion 2</option>
    <option value="valor3"> Opcion 3</option>
</select>
```

Y para obtener el valor de la opción que el usuario escogió con javascript se hace así:

```
var valor = document.getElementById("opciones").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Aumenta el Attribute 'multiple' a un select.

```html
<select id="opciones" multiple >
    <option value="valor1">Opcion 1</option>
    <option value="valor2">Opcion 2</option>
    <option value="valor3">Opcion 3</option>
    <option value="valor3">Opcion 4</option>
    <option value="valor3">Opcion 5</option>
</select>
```

mas información en [HTML  multiple Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_select_multiple.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar [la etiqueta Select de html](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) y agregar [la etiqueta optgroup](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp) para categorizar las opciones.

Espero te sirva

```html
<select>
  <option value="0" style="display:none">Selecciones una opción</option>
  <optgroup label="España">
    <option value="1">Islas Canarias</option>
    <option value="2">Peninsula</option>
    <option value="3">Ceuta y Melilla</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Estados Unidos">
    <option value="4">New Yor</option>
    <option value="5">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="5">Massachusetts</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```